# Function that takes a reference of a const object but no r-value

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference

is it currently possible to write functions, that take references of `const` qualified objects, but no r-values?

```
// Takes no r-values
void foo(std::string& v) {
    ...
}
...
const string cstr("constant string");
foo("string"); // this does not compile, as wanted
foo(cstr); // this does not compile, as expected. But i would want it to 
...
```

---

```
// Takes r-values, which is highly undesired
void foo2(const std::string& v) {
    ...
}
...
const string cstr("constant string");
foo("string"); // this does compile, but i want it to fail.
foo(cstr); // this does compile
...
```

The background of the question has to do with a copy of the object at a later point in time (After foo has finished). Basically the reference is pushed to a queue and dealt with later. I know, that the semantics are messed up and a `shared_ptr` or alike would be desired. But i am tied to outer constraints.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Perhaps explain those "outer constraints"?

Comment: Would a deleted function overload suffice?

Comment: It is part of a serialisation algorithm in a hpc application. The input may be very big and unneccessary copies are unwanted due to performance drops. If i transform it into a shared pointer, i have one more deep copy.

Comment: "If i transform it into a shared pointer, i have one more deep copy" - how so?

Comment: @Ron thats a very good idea.

Comment: It's probably possible to build something with ``type_traits`` and template specializations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use deleted function overloads:

```
void foo(std::string& v) {
    std::cout << v;
}
void foo(const std::string& v) = delete;
void foo(const char* v) = delete;
```

or similar.

Comment: Very nice and non-trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can explicitly allow const references while disallowing r-value refs:

```
void foo(const std::string& v) {
}

void foo(std::string& v) {
}

void foo(std::string&& v) = delete;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. @Ron has come up with a similar approach.